# What are the steps to solve this recurrence relation using iteration method?

Tags: algorithm, iteration

I'm relatively new to analyzing time complexities of algorithms, and hopelessly stuck on this problem.

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(n) ; n>1
T(1) = a
```

I've come to understand that there's an easy solution to this using the master's method, but *I'd like to know how to perform this analysis using the iteration method*.

Comment: Does this link help? Look at the second example in it: 
https://www.codesdope.com/course/algorithms-lets-iterate/

Comment: Yeah, I could apply that concept here. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `theta(n)` with `n` for simplicity. (To do the question thoroughly, you have to expand the definition of `theta(n)` out to get upper and lower bounds for this term, and run the same analysis as below -- it's extremely rare to see this done in practice).

Assuming for now that `n` is a power of 2:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n
     = 4T(n/4) + n + n
     = 8T(n/8) + n + n + n
     = ...
     = 2^kT(n/2^k) + kn
```

Eventually, n/2^k is 1, and that's when k is log_2(n).

So `T(n) = nT(1) + log_2(n)*n`

This is valid for `n` a power of 2, but you can note that if `n1` is the largest power of 2 less than or equal to `n`, and `n2` is the smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to `n`, then `T(n1) <= T(n) <= T(n2)`, which you can combine with the facts that `n1 >= n/2`, `n2 <= 2n` to get theta(n log n) bounds for all n.

The calculation or working that you will most often see is the same as the above, but not stating that `n` must be a power of 2, and completely glossing over the rounding details. Sedgewick is one author who works through these details rigorously, for example when he computes the exact number of comparisons performed in a merge sort of an array of length n.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, brother! The first half of your reply was the answer I was looking for. But I'd like to learn more about this concept, so could you maybe explain this paragraph in a bit more detail? "This is valid for n a power of 2.. ". Or, if you could tell me the name of the book authored by Sedgwick, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Sedgewick&Flajolet "Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms" presents the analysis of mergesort for n a power of 2 on p19, and solves it exactly starting on p70. It's not _quite_ the same recurrence relation, because it's T(n) = T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceil(n/2)) + n

Comment: You might accept this answer if it's what you were looking for.